# Can we use same jquery plugin twice in a single page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Ive been trying to add a slider model to the webpage and I want to add the sliders in two different divs.. Ive tried renaming the elements and class names..bt it doesnt wrk... Is there a solution for this???is it possible to use a jquery plug in twice in same page??

I am trying to add the plugin code

```
      var currentPosition1 = 0;
                  var slideWidth1 = 900;
                  var slides1 = $('.slider1');
                  var numberOfSlides1 = slides1.length;

                  // Remove scrollbar in JS
                  $('#slidesContainer1').css('overflow', 'hidden');

                  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
                  slides1
                    .wrapAll('')
                    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
                    .css({
                      'float' : 'left',
                      'width' : slideWidth1
                    });

                  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
                  $('#slideInner1').css('width', slideWidth1 * numberOfSlides1);

                  // Insert controls in the DOM
                  $('#slideshow1')
                    .prepend('Clicking moves left')
                    .append('Clicking moves right');

                  // Hide left arrow control on first load
                  manageControls1(currentPosition1);

                  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
                  $('.control')
                    .bind('click', function(){
                    // Determine new position
                    currentPosition1 = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl1') ? currentPosition1+1 : currentPosition1-1;

                    // Hide / show controls
                    manageControls1(currentPosition1);
                    // Move slideInner using margin-left
                    $('#slideInner1').animate({
                      'marginLeft' : slideWidth1*(-currentPosition1)
                    });
                  });

                  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
                  function manageControls1(position1){
                    // Hide left arrow if position is first slider2
                    if(position1==0){ $('#leftControl1').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl1').show() }
                    // Hide right arrow if position is last slider2
                    if(position1==numberOfSlides1-1){ $('#rightControl1').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl1').show() }
                  }
```

in to the div Panel1

```
<div class="panel1">
    <div id="slideshow1">
       <div id="slidesContainer1">




          <div class="slider1">
                <table style="margin-bottom:50px;"><tbody id="facetPrsnRslt"></tbody></table>
           </div>
           <div class="slider1">
               <p>This is the END my Friend...</p>
           </div>
      </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

, there is another div panel 2,
i want to add the same slider plugin in to panel2, bt no luck...

Comment: What you tried? What doesn't work? Why you think it doesnt work (Error, Exception)?

Comment: i am trying to add the slider feature... so slider in the first div wrks perfectly, bt the slider will not wrk in the second div..It doesnt giv any error message..

Comment: A little code might help a lot.

Comment: Im using demo 1 inside http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

so you have a set of code that does what you want it to do, but want to use it in more than one element? What you have there is just plain "user-script" - a set of codes that does something you want... and that's it, magic is done. If you want to make it reusable and scalable, try building a *real* plugin, something that can do:

```
$('set_of_elements').myOwnPlugin({option:'foo'});
```

If you want to delve into the specifics of plugin development, take a look into [this article](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) which explains it thoroughly (and it may be confusing at first). They, after you get a hang of the basics, you might want to get a "template" for building the structure of the plugin code. There are 2 boilerplates I personally use, [this one](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) and [this one](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/). the former uses a modified version of the one in the jQuery article, the other uses a OOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the plugin, we can't say all plugin can be used twice in one html file. But that specific plugin seems to work. I wonder if you was changing the class or the id, I was seeing the source code of the plugin and it needs the classes to put some CSS, but the container id is what you have to use to initialize the slideshows

```
<div id="showcase1" class="showcase">
<!-- contents needed for the showcase -->
</div>
<div id="showcase2" class="showcase">
<!-- contents needed for the showcase -->
</div>
```

In the javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#showcase1").awShowcase({ /* config of this showcase */ });
    $("#showcase2").awShowcase({ /* config of this showcase */ });
})
```

Here is an example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6qkjbqdh/

I noticed that the plugin is using an old version of jQuery (1.5.2), keep in mind that perhaps, the version you included in your project can be more recent and that may cause issues.

Regards